# Chrome, Opera, Mozilla Content decoding failed

Tags: php, firefox, google-chrome, decode

I have a function in php, which lists followers of a user in twitter. When I use chrome to navigate to the page which holds the function, It works, sometimes it doesn't.

Chrome works 3 out of 5 times before it gives "Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error"

Mozilla works 4 out of 5 times before it gives "Content Encoding Error"

Opera shows this

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\wamp\www\ntwyt\core\common\twitter.php on line 1639
>   �j&x���o��4�a  ���h��RA�N����T.&�Km�n� 5ý i�<Т
>   K���/o4�¨�b�@�Y�����

Here's the code

```
function theme_followers($feed, $hide_pagination = false) {
    $rows = array();
    if (count($feed) == 0 || $feed == '[]') return '<p>No users to display.</p>';

    foreach ($feed->users->user as $user) {

        $name = theme('full_name', $user);
        $tweets_per_day = twitter_tweets_per_day($user);
        $last_tweet = strtotime($user->status->created_at);
        $content = "{$name}<br /><span class='about'>";
        if($user->description != "")
            $content .= "Bio: " . twitter_parse_tags($user->description) . "<br />";
        if($user->location != "")
            $content .= "Location: {$user->location}<br />";
        $content .= "Info: ";
        $content .= pluralise('tweet', $user->statuses_count, true) . ", ";
        $content .= pluralise('friend', $user->friends_count, true) . ", ";
        $content .= pluralise('follower', $user->followers_count, true) . ", ";
        $content .= "~" . pluralise('tweet', $tweets_per_day, true) . " per day<br />";
        $content .= "Last tweet: ";
        if($user->protected == 'true' && $last_tweet == 0)
            $content .= "Private";
        else if($last_tweet == 0)
            $content .= "Never tweeted";
        else
            $content .= twitter_date('l jS F Y', $last_tweet);
        $content .= "</span>";

        $rows[] = array('data' => array(array('data' => theme('avatar', theme_get_avatar($user)), 'class' => 'avatar'),
                                        array('data' => $content, 'class' => 'status shift')),
                        'class' => 'tweet');

    }

    $content = theme('table', array(), $rows, array('class' => 'followers'));
    if (!$hide_pagination)
    $content .= theme('list_pagination', $feed);
    return $content;
}
```

Whats the problem? It works and doesn't work.

Comment: I'd put a `var_dump($feed)` in front of the `foreach` to see what kind of variable you get passed. It's likely that on one of those passes, you do not receive a proper feed. That could result from anything on the connection link, such as bad response from Twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to loop:

```
foreach ($feed->users as $user) {
    ....
}
```